# How to run a background task in Sinatra to avoid Heroku 30 second timout

Tags: ruby, heroku, sinatra

I am building a Sinatra application to process PDFs using Ghostscript, however when I pushed it to Heroku, it times out because Ghostscript takes longer than 30 seconds processing the PDF.

I need a way to either run the Ghostscript command in the background and show a loading indicator until it's done, or else I need to continually ping the server until the processing is complete. I searched for a couple  weeks how to complete this and nothing has worked.

This is my POST action:

```rb
post '/process_pdf' do
    unless params[:file] && params[:file][:tempfile] && params[:file][:filename]
      return erb :form
    end

    @filename = params[:file][:filename].gsub!(/[^0-9A-Za-z.]/, '')
    @output_file_name = "#{Time.now.strftime('%b_%d_%I_%M')}_#{@filename}"
    @file = params[:file][:tempfile]

    File.open("#{settings.root}/tmp/#{@filename}", 'wb') do |file|
      file.write(@file.read)
      file.close
    end

    # @pdf = GS.run("#{settings.root}/tmp/#{@filename}") do |command|
    #   command.option(GS::PDFA)
    #   command.option(GS::BATCH)
    #   command.option(GS::NO_PAUSE)
    #   command.option(GS::PROCESS_COLOR_MODEL, 'DeviceCMYK')
    #   command.option(GS::DEVICE, 'pdfwrite')
    #   command.option(GS::PDFA_COMPATIBILITY_POLICY, '1')
    #   command.option('CompatibilityLevel', '1.4')
    #   command.option('PDFSETTINGS', 'prepress')
    #   command.option(GS::OUTPUT_FILE,
    #                  "#{settings.root}/tmp/#{@output_file_name}")
    # end

    # until @pdf.success?
    #   puts 'loading...'
    #   sleep 1
    # end

    Kernel.system 'gs -dPDFA -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE'\
                  ' -sProcessColorModel=DeviceCMYK'\
                  ' -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sPDFACompatibilityPolicy=1'\
                  ' -dCompatibilityLevel=1.4 -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress'\
                  " -sOutputFile=#{settings.root}/tmp/#{@output_file_name}"\
                  " #{settings.root}/tmp/#{@filename}"

    erb :process_pdf
  end
```

And display once processing is complete:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<%= url("/style.css")%>">
    <title>Processing PDF</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <%= send_file "#{settings.root}/tmp/#{@output_file_name}" %>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In my POST action I tried multiple ways of processing the PDF with Ghostscript, and nothing sped it up enough to be within that 30-second timeout on Heroku. I even tried checking the `success?` of the `Process::Status` (which is what the gs-ruby gem is providing) but by the time it even hit that block, it had already processed and was already too late.

This works fine locally, it's not until it's on Heroku that it fails because processing took too long.

Comment: Can you provide the Timeout error. Timeout can refer to many things. Like process taking too long to finish, webpage not answering within time, ...

Comment: hey @TinNguyen, thanks for responding! The error code on papertrail is `at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout" method=POST path="/process_pdf" status=503`

Comment: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/request-timeout "The timeout value is not configurable. If your server requires longer than 30 seconds to complete a given request, we recommend moving that work to a background task or worker to periodically ping your server to see if the processing request has been finished. This pattern frees your web processes up to do more work, and decreases overall application response times." Your PDF processing is a blocking call as in nothing else gets computed before that one is done. You'll need to create a background task or a separate worker.

Comment: I know, that's why i asked the question. With sinatra, adding a background task is not as easy as installing the sidekiq gem would be on rails. I haven't found a good solution for creating background tasks in sinatra, which is what i was hoping someone could recommend

Comment: While Sinatra is a wonderful server environment, it's also not as full-featured as others, so it might not be capable of doing what you want. [Padrino](http://padrinorb.com/) is the next step up from my experience, then you get into Rails.

Comment: When asked to clarify or add more information, please edit the question and incorporate the additional information as if it'd been there initially. Don't answer with information in comments because you force us to read every comment and try to piece it together. Don't use "edit" or "update" tags to mark changes as we can see what changed and when if we need to.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use DelayedJob (https://github.com/collectiveidea/delayed_job). It's the most simple background job processor you can set up given your architecture and it only requires a database to store and process jobs.